# How to update value in a class objecct in php

Tags: php, oop

I have one file user.php with constructor for the client:

```
    class Client{
    public $name;
    public $pin;
    public $balance;

    function __construct($name, $pin, $balance){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->pin = $pin;
        $this->balance = $balance;
    }
} 
$client1 = new Client("Alan", "0201", 2000);
                                                                                    
?>
```

Also I have a file where i do some math to the client object:

```
$balance = $client1->balance;

function withdrow($amount, $balance){
    $currentBalance = $balance - $amount;
    if($balance < $amount){
        echo "You are low on balance";
    }
    else{
        $client1->balance = $currentBalance;
        return $currentBalance;
    }
}
```

And 3rd html file where I include First file with the client and I want to echo the updated value of balance on the screen.But its print the value set in client.How to update the balance.

My code look like this right now but setter not change the value balance:

```
class Client{
public $name;
private $pin;
private $balance;

function __construct($name, $pin, $balance){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->pin = $pin;
    $this->balance = $balance;
}
private function setPin($pin){
     $this->pin = $pin;
  }
public function getPin(){
    return $this->pin;
  }

public function setBalance($balance){
     $this->balance = $balance;
  }

public function getBalance(){
    return $this->balance;
  }

} 

$client1 = new Client("Alan", "0201", 2000);
```

Comment: your client class property must be private and have setter

Comment: Can you give me a example for setter I try to set but is not returning a value

Comment: you can see `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-getters-and-setters-methods-in-php`

Comment: you need edit your code ?

Comment: Actually  the setter is not updating the balance I get same result.I update the code in question.

Comment: you must updating with call by reference  `function (&$VariableName){}`

Comment: getter and setter is for better code :)

Answer (score 0):

you must call function with call by reference

```php
function withdrow($amount, &$balance){ /** call by reference */ 
   $currentBalance = $balance - $amount;
   if($balance < $amount){
       echo "You are low on balance";
   }
   else{
       $client1->balance = $currentBalance;
       return $currentBalance;
   }
}
```